# Stubborn Chest Fat/One side of chest length longer

Tags: body-fat, chest

I have two questions regarding [this picture of myself](http://phantzm.com/IMG_0002.JPG):

1. How can I get rid of that stubborn chest fat that's surrounding my nipples?
2. As you can see the right side of my chest is longer than my left side. What can I do about that?

I started jogging/walking (80% walk + 20% jog) should I continue it? What should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diet will fix the chest fat. Eat a healthy, balanced diet, so: vegetables, grain(but not white flour!), fruit, lots of water(this really helps, my best advice is to drink a glass of water as soon as you urinate. This will make you use the restroom a lot for a few days but after that it'll normalize and you'll simply be drinking a lot of water - that makes the hormone receptors stick further out of your cells' lipid bilayer so they're more receptive), and meat, milk and eggs, but those three in moderation.

Dissymmetry with the pectoralis muscles is really common. Actually, I'm sure it's common on all muscles, but the pectoralis are very close together so it's visible. In any case, there's nothing you can do about it. But you still have a layer of fat over them, so who knows, maybe they're actually quite symmetric.

Walking and jogging is great. If you aren't doing any other exercising, I'd suggest some bodyweight exercises: pushup, chinup, australian pushups (reverse pushups), planks, wall sits. 
Also, jump rope is great.

Answer (score 0):

It's a two pronged question deserving of a two pronged answer:

**Getting Rid of Stubborn Fat**

This requires a diet change, and perhaps a look at your grooming products.  Focus on whole foods and lean sources of protein.  You may want to have your T levels checked as well.  The Art of Manliness put together a nice 4 part series on testosterone and what you can do if you have low T:

- [Testosterone Week: The Declining Virility of Men and the Importance of T](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2013/01/13/testosterone-week-intro/)
- [Testosterone Week: The Benefits of Optimal Testosterone](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2013/01/14/testosterone-benefits/)
- [Testosterone Week: A Short Primer on How T Is Made](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2013/01/15/how-testosterone-is-made/)
- [Testosterone Week: What’s a “Normal” Testosterone Level and How to Measure Your T](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2013/01/16/normal-testosterone-levels/)
- [Testosterone Week: How I Doubled My Testosterone Levels Naturally and You Can Too](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2013/01/18/how-to-increase-testosterone-naturally/)

The articles are very accessible to folks who are not doctors, and at least gives you an idea of what affects T levels, what normal T levels are, and what you can do about it without resorting to crazy measures.  A couple of the takeaways from the final installment are:

- Your diet should have higher fat/cholesterol content
- You need some sort of resistance training--whether barbell or body weight.
- Avoid common xenoestrogens (note: grooming/cleaning products not mentioned in the article that also work are Every Man Jack and Bert's Bees)

**One Side Longer Than the Other**

This may be a dissymmetry in fat distribution, or in the underlying muscle.  Perhaps even a little of both.  In order to "correct" muscular dissymmetry you should use unilateral movements.  Basically you are working the left and right side independently.  For example, doing dumbbell presses with one arm at a time, and adding an extra rep or two to the side that is smaller.  To correct unsymmetrical fat distributions you need to get rid of excess fat.

The combination of losing fat and gaining muscle will help correct the things you are concerned about.